# sqs order by value asc

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query in a php file. I want to order the results by ascending values from a column in one of the tables using 'ORDER by value ASC'. However, the results being produced by the current query are not ordering by this value, but another value in the table. I presume this is because i have the syntax wrong but i cant work out how. I have been trying to work this out for a few weeks but no joy, can anybody help?

Thanks very much in advance for any replies.

Query:

```
$Find_Query3 = mysql_query("SELECT 
patients.*, 
addobs.*, 
DATE_FORMAT(addobs.datetime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as dti1,
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(addobs.datetime), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM addobs WHERE addobs.mrn = patients.mrn AND addobs.datetime >= lastOkPar.lastDatetime AND addobs.par >= $par AND addobs.hidden != 'yes') as dti2
FROM addobs 
INNER JOIN patients ON addobs.MRN = patients.MRN
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
 addobs.MRN 
 , MAX(addobs.datetime) as lastDatetime
FROM addobs
WHERE
 addobs.par < $par
 AND addobs.hidden != 'yes'
GROUP BY addobs.MRN
) lastOkPar ON lastOkPar.MRN = addobs.MRN
WHERE 
addobs.datetime = (SELECT MAX(OLAST.datetime) FROM addobs AS OLAST WHERE OLAST.MRN = patients.MRN)
AND addobs.par >= $par 
AND NOT addobs.hidden = 'yes'
AND COALESCE(patients.ward,'') != 'dc'    
ORDER by addobs.par ASC, dti2 ASC
```

PS currently the results are ordered by date of birth, which is one of the columns from 'patients'. I dont know why it has chosen to order by this. Im sure there is logic but i havnt worked it out!

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ORDER by addobs.par , 
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(addobs.datetime), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM addobs WHERE      addobs.mrn = patients.mrn AND addobs.datetime >= lastOkPar.lastDatetime AND addobs.par >= $par   AND addobs.hidden != 'yes')
```